# vscode extension using execa returns EPERM

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Currently writing a vscode extension and testing on mac osx. Need to automate some npm commands using execa. After the recent round of vscode updates we are no longer able to run our existing commands.

```
 async runScript(script: string, cwd?: string) {
  const scriptStdOut = execa.command(script, {
    shell: true,
    cwd: cwd,
    windowsVerbatimArguments: true,
  })
  let out = await scriptStdOut
  return out
}
```

Error: failed with exit code 1 (EPERM): npx ng update @angular/cli @angular/core